# jQuery Color Plugin - $.Color is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the example from [jquery-color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) work, but it's giving me the `$.Color is not a function` error. What am I doing wrong?

Relevant code bit:

```
$("#sat").click(function(){
  $("#block").animate({
      backgroundColor: $.Color({ saturation: 0 })
  }, 1500 );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you did not reference correctly the javascript file, or not in the correct order.

Check you reference first jQuery, then the Color plugin:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.color.min.js"></script>
```

Verify the path to both scripts is correct.

Comment: Since I couldn't find the `min` version in the repositories I downloaded some random one from a random source. There was the problem. Thanks!